# R Script Function not returning data

Tags: r, list, function

I've been searching for a while now and can't seem to come up with an answer. I'm just creating a simple function for some statistical data that I'm pulling from a list and manipulating it and create averages and whatnot. The function isn't returning anything though. No errors are being produced and the matrix is being created.

Source:

```
library(matrixStats)
source("Control_Function.R")

mydata <- read.table("DataSmall.txt")
length <- nrow(mydata)
a<-length/11
#begining control limits

control(mydata)
```

Control_Function.R

```
control <- function(arg1){
      mat1 <-matrix(unlist(arg1),11,25)
      matAverage <-colMeans(mat1)
      matSdAv <- colSds(mat1)
      sbar <-mean(matSdAv)
      xbarbar<-mean(matAverage)
      newlist<-list(matAverage, matSdAv, sbar, xbarbar)
      return(newlist)

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How are you calling the script?

Comment: If you're running the top level script using `source` as well then you need to add a print statement if you want to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to *see* the answers, then you need to add "print" like this:

```
 control <- function(arg1){
  mat1 <-matrix(unlist(arg1),11,25)
  print(matAverage <-colMeans(mat1))
  print(matSdAv <- colSds(mat1))
  print(sbar <-mean(matSdAv))
  print(xbarbar<-mean(matAverage))
  newlist<-list(matAverage, matSdAv, sbar, xbarbar)
  return(newlist)

}
```

If you want to actually *save* one of those objects to your workspace (not the function environment), then add a <<- like this to the object you want to save (I made the object I wanted to add to the workspace "newlist"):

```
 control <- function(arg1){
  mat1 <-matrix(unlist(arg1),11,25)
  print(matAverage <-colMeans(mat1))
  print(matSdAv <- colSds(mat1))
  print(matSdAv)
  print(sbar <-mean(matSdAv))
  print(xbarbar<-mean(matAverage))
  newlist <<- list(matAverage, matSdAv, sbar, xbarbar)

}
```